# How to find the current HTML's name through JavaScript when imported into a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that imports other html pages into a div through jQuery's load function:

```
$("#divId").load(pageLocation);
```

Each of the imported pages has an id associated to its name (page1.html, page2.html, etc) and I know it can access the div's page's code and call its variables.

My problem is I need the current imported page to retrieve its own Id in order to compare it to a variable in the parent page, but when I use `window.location.pathname` it gives me the parent page's name instead.

Is there a way to retrieve the imported page's name without having to declare by hand the id in all the imported pages?

And no, I can't use the `pageLocation` in the parent page to do the comparison instead. 
On some occasions there is more than one div importing pages, but I can't have them all execute their own code all at the same time. That's why I need each page to know its own identity, to check if they're the currently active or not.

Comment: what is `pageLocation` ? the name of the page should be in pageLocation var

Comment: It's a variable I use to find the location of the imported html page in the folders

Comment: "I know it can access the div's page's code and call its variables." Huh? What does this mean? I think you need to re-word this question.

Comment: I found out the difference between importing a page through an iframe or into a div is the level of access. In an iframe the page retains its identity and knows it's a child page, so you need to provide the correct path.Through a div however the imported page acts like it's part of the parent page itself and doesn't need the path to access the parent's variables. That's why I'm having so much trouble in dynamically find its own identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a page like that it's DOM becomes part of the parent DOM. The concept of the pages file name no longer exists. If you used an iFrame instead of a div and altered the src you would have that to work with. You can add an attribute to the div you load that page into and store the info there. Or you can keep some global variables that identify which divs in the parent have which pages loaded at the current time. You could also Use the id attribute of the body tag and store the file name in that.

Really you just need to shift your view point and understand that when you load into a div, you just added (or replaced) the contents of your parent page, you do not have a page nested inside another page as you would with an iFrame

Comment: I know that difference between the iframe and the div, but I was hoping there was some way to work that around. Sadly in my code it needs to be the imported page to tell if it's the currently active or not and not the parent, like in most cases

Answer (score 1):

The page you loaded is no longer a page once loaded, it's part of the current page. If you want to save any information about the original page, I'd recommend storing it in JavaScript variables or in data attributes on the element you're inserting the content into.